# How can I add the z-score and its confidence interval from an estimate using emmeans?

Tags: r, z-score, lsmeans

I'm trying to add to the following model the z-score value and its confidence interval after using the `emmeans` package.

The model:

```
m <- lmer(mode_usual_dic ~ intervention * time + fas  + distance_walking +
         gender + (1|center/ID), data = df)
```

The function:

```
emmeans2 <- function(model, specs, by) {
  em1 <- emmeans(object = model, specs = specs, by = by)
  em2 <- emmeans(object = model, specs = specs, by = by) |> confint()
  
  em2$contrasts$p.value <- as.data.frame(em1$contrasts)$p.value
  
  em2$contrasts <- em2$contrasts |> 
    mutate(p.value = ifelse(p.value < 0.01, '< 0.01', round(p.value, 3)))
  
  return(em2)
}
```

The interaction:

```
em1 <- emmeans2(m, specs = pairwise~intervention, by = 'time')
em2 <- emmeans2(m, specs = pairwise~time, by = 'intervention')
```

The contrast:

```
em1$contrasts |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  select(-SE, -df) |> 
  flextable(cwidth = 0.5) |> 
  add_header_lines('Contrasts between Groups') |> 
  autofit()
```

Therefore the question is how can I also add the z-score and its confidence interval to the final output.

Comment: A Z-score has no confidence interval, it is a sample property (and not a population parameter). The score itself is just the inverse normal quantile of the *P*-value, possibly with the sign of the point estimate added back in. I'm almost certain that `emmeans` returns t-statistics which are probably to be preferred anyway.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.